# Docker: Using COPY when the Dockerfile is located in a subdirectory

Tags: docker, copy, docker-compose, dockerfile, directory-structure

I'm building an app using [multiple dockerfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409761/multiple-dockerfiles-in-project) (one for each service). My app's directory structure is as follows:

```
app
├── dockerfiles
│   ├── webserver
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── database
│       └── Dockerfile
├── public
    └── <frontend>
├── db
    └── <data>
  [...]
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── docker-compose.yml
```

In my webserver's `Dockerfile`, I want to copy in my existing code using the `COPY` command:

```
# Dockerfile
COPY ./public /var/www/html
```

And I want to deploy the app using my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
   webserver:
      build: ./dockerfiles/webserver
      image: webserver:php-apache
```

However, when I run `docker-compose` from the working directory (`app`), I get the following error:

```
Building webserver
Step 1/2 : FROM php:7.1.11-apache-jessie
 ---> cb6a5015ad72
Step 2/2 : COPY ./public /var/www/html
Service 'webserver' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder193736188/public: no such file or directory
```

This error disappears if I move my webserver's `Dockerfile` to the app's root, so I know that it's being caused by a paths or build context issue.

And knowing this, we can fix the problem one of two ways, by either:

(1) Using one `Dockerfile` for the entire app (in the app's root), or

```
app
└── Dockerfile
```

(2) Using multiple `Dockerfiles` for each service (in the app's root).

```
app
├── Dockerfile.webserver
└── Dockerfile.database
```

These solutions are bad because using one dockerfile/container for everything is not [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern) (1), and having multiple dockerfiles organized in this way just looks messy (2).

---

**So, My Question is:**

How do we fix this problem without changing our original directory structure?

- *What changes need to be made to the dockerfiles, to `docker-compose.yml`, or to the basic runtime commands?*
- *Is there a better way to organize everything?*
- *What about the `WORKDIR` command?*

Ideally, the best solution should work for both dev (local) and production (remote) environments, so let's avoid volumes for now...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

All you need to do here is add `context: .` and `dockerfile` in your build section inside your docker-compose.yml file so that your service understands the complete directory structure.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/webserver/Dockerfile
    image: webserver:php-apache
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I knew it had to be an issue with the build context, but I had so much trouble looking for a solution... Hopefully this will help someone in a similar situation in the near future!

Answer (score 26):

Not exactly OP's scenario, but if you're not using `docker-compose`, you can also specify context and Dockerfile separately:

```bash
docker build . -f app/dockerfiles/webserver/Dockerfile
```

This builds with the current directory `.` as the context, but uses the `Dockerfile` from the subdirectory.

Answer (score 9):

As already clarified elsewhere a combination of `context` and `dockerfile` does the trick. I only want to add that you don't even need to locate the `docker-compose.yml` file itself in your application's root directory for that to work.

For example, in one of my projects I have multiple compose configurations to support several environments (*development*, *staging*, *production*, etc.) and I decided to put everything in their own subdirectories, for cleanliness. My directory tree is as follows:

```
.
+-- README.md
+-- scripts
|   +-- docker
|       +-- compose.yml
|       +-- compose-stage.yml
|       +-- compose-prod.yml
|       +-- dockerfile
|       +-- ...
|   +-- ...
```

where `compose.yml` would be as follows:

```
# compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./scripts/docker/dockerfile
....
```

Note the `context`, which points to the application's root directory - two levels up from the directory the `compose.yml` file is located into - and the `dockerfile`, which is relative to the `context`.

With the above directory tree and `compose.yml` file, all that we have to do is running the following command **from the application's root directory** (the directory where `README.md` is located, that is):

```
> docker compose -f scripts/docker/compose.yml up
```

and everything works like charm!

I know sounds a bit convoluted, and probably it is, but the time spent will be repaid with interests when the time comes to deal with the deployment of the application to three (or more!) different environments.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

The scope for the `COPY` instruction is the folder where Dockerfile is. My suggestion is to change your Dockerfile to public folder and change the instruction to `COPY . /var/www/html`.