# Using automated build with Github Actions and Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have long been struggling already with the automatic build of my Dockerfile (located in a subdirectory) using Github Actions.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app
├── .github
│   ├── workflows
│   │   └── build.yml
├── encoding
│   ├── encoder.py
│   └── Dockerfile
├── database
│   └── Dockerfile
├── db
    └── <data>
  [...]
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

My `build.yml` is as follows (for limitation purposes, only included the build of the `encoding` step):

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
jobs:
  encoding_build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
    - name: Login to private Docker registry 
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.8'
    - name: Build Docker image 
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: ../../../encoding
        dockerfile: ./encoding/Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: <username>/<project_name>:<tag>
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
```

And my Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app/

ADD ./pyproject.toml /tmp/ 
ADD ./poetry.lock /tmp/
RUN cp /tmp/pyproject.toml /tmp/poetry.lock /app/

RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root --no-dev -vvv

COPY encoder.py /app/

WORKDIR /app/

CMD ["python", "encoder.py", "--input_file", "/app/input.txt", "--output_file", "/app/output.txt", "--model_name_or_path", "bert-base-uncased"]
```

I have checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785706/docker-using-copy-when-the-dockerfile-is-located-in-a-subdirectory), and I created my context and dockerfile arguments based on the answers of vivekyad4v and Sal Borrelli there; yet the automated build doesn't seem to work. When pushing any changes to my repository, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: unable to prepare context: path "../../../encoding" not found
```

I'd highly appreciate if someone could help me out on how to resolve my error. Furthermore, any additional Docker or Github Actions related comments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey your context path is incorrect I believe.

You could try something like this:

```yaml
with:
  context: ./encoding
  file: ./encoding/Dockerfile
```

Your current working directory should already be `/app`.

And the `context` in your `build.yml` like for the `dockerfile` will be resolved using the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Sadly, I got a different error message after changing the context to `./encoding`:

```Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /tmp/buildkit-mount3478190059/Dockerfile: no such file or directory```


Same issue is present after changing the dockerfile argument from `./encoding/Dockerfile` to `encoding/Dockerfile`

Comment: I also tried changing dockerfile argument to `app/encoding/Dockerfile` but same issue as above.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action)

It's not `dockerfile` but `file` that have to be used, like this:
```yml
with:
  context: ./encoding
  file: ./encoding/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Also i suggest you should use the latest actions available: 
```docker/build-push-action@v4```

Answer (score 1):

I did try something new when the error kept on persisting.Which is restart my IDE.
Sometime the issue is not that complicated as we may think.